# Laravel: URL::route() print only the route link without the website name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this route

```
Route::get('/dashboard', array(
            'as' => 'dashboard-get',
            'uses' => 'AppController@getDashboard'
));
```

In the View if i write

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('dashboard-get') }}">Dashboard</a>
```

It will return me the entire link.

```
http://192.168.0.1/dashboard
```

How can get the route by name in the VIEW and only print the

```
/dashboard
```

Without the `http://192.168.0.1/` part of the link

Comment: `route(string $name, mixed $parameters = array(), bool $absolute = true, Route $route = null)` By default $absolute is set to true make it false you will get relative URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [code source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L220), `route` method generate an absolute URL by default, you may set it to false:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('dashboard-get',array(),false) }}">Dashboard</a>
```

**Update**

You can also define your own custom links by

```
HTML::macro('Rlinks',function($routeName,$parameters = array(),$name){ 
    return "<a href=".substr(URL::route($routeName,$parameters,false), 1) .">"
       .$name.
    "</a>";
});
```

Then call your macro

```
{{ HTML::Rlinks('dashboard-get',array(),'Dashboard') }}
```

Comment: Many thanks, would it also be possible to get only "dashboard" without "/" ?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can use `substr(URL::route(...),1)` method (answer updated).

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
app('router')->getRoutes()->getByName('dashboard-get')->uri();
```