# Generating relative urls with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relative-url

Is it possible, with laravel 4, to generate relatives url to use in forms and links ?

For example I have a form where I'd like to use a relative url to **/user/login** and laravel build the form with the full url **http: //url.com/user/login**

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26205470/3192276) answer

Comment: excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for, I have overridden the form macro so its render relatives urls :) can you make an answers so I can accept it ?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is helper functions.

[Laravel helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers)

## secure_url

Generate a fully qualified URL to a given path using HTTPS.

```
echo secure_url('foo/bar', $parameters = array());
```

## url

Generate a fully qualified URL to the given path.

```
echo url('foo/bar', $parameters = array(), $secure = null);
```

Comment: this is kind of problematic as in development mode, my url are all in http as I don't want to install an SSL certificate for each app. So I would like the app to respond to either http or https depending on the proxy

Comment: @kitensei With `url()` you shouldn't have that problem. It will detect the current scheme (http or https) and use that to generate the URL. `secure_url()` and the third parameter of `url()` are only there to *force* https.